Quarto is Not Showing Images in Word Output
I am using Quarto in R to render Word Documents. My document settings are as follows:
---
title: "Project"
format: docx
project:
  output-dir: "/directory_path/"
editor: visual
bibliography: references.bib
reference-section-title: References
---

The code runs a complete render without error, but images that I have embedded are not showing up, only the image name. The image shows up with a preview in the editor, so I think the pathway I have is correct.
I've tried changing the sizing and tried using \begin{figure} ... \end{figure}, but I cannot get the images to show up in the Word output. I've been following the Quarto documentation for embedding images: link here.
Any suggestions?
Thank you!

\begin{figure} is Latex-specific.
Here is a minimal example about how to correctly render images with Word output:
---
title: "Project"
format: docx
project:
  output-dir: "./directory_path/"
---

Here is some text

Here is an image:

![image](Polar_Bear_-_Alaska.jpg)

I got the image from here: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ursus_maritimus#/media/Archivo:Polar_Bear_-_Alaska.jpg
